# How to calculate median in the last 30 days - Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with transactions from a lot of clients. I want to find the median for the last 30 days(for every day) for each client. I know that PERCENTILE_CONT would do that but I can't use this with rolling dates.

I tried this but it last for 30 minutes on Bigquery and consume a lot of resources:

```
select 
  user_id,
  date,
  rolling_avg_spend,
  (select distinct percentile_cont(spend, 0.5) over() 
   from unnest(rolling_spends) spend
  ) as rolling_median_spend
from (
  select 
    user_id,
    date,
    avg(spend) over(partition by user_id order by daterows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as rolling_avg_spend,
    array_agg(spend) over(partition by user_id order by date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as rolling_spends,
  from monthly_spend  
)
```

Sample input:

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: Do you have sample input and sample output that you could show please?

Comment: I added on the question.